# Entry Format Validation in Jira using ScriptRunner

Tags: groovy, jira

I need to validate format of data entered by a user for "My Field" in Jira using ScriptRunner.

User entry should consists of a prefix (always "ABCD") and a suffix (a number), e.g. ABCD12345.

Problems with my code:

1. If a user enter any string less than 9 characters, no validation happens; it has to be 9 characters or more.
2. Doesn't matter what a user enter for a prefix - no prefix validation at all.
3. For string equal or more than 9 characters, only suffix is validated (characters from 5 to 9).

   ```
   import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.util.UserMessageUtil
   import com.opensymphony.workflow.InvalidInputException

   String field = getFieldByName("My Example Field").getValue()

   String prefix = field.substring(0, 4);
   String suffix = field.substring(4, 9);

   if (!prefix == "ABCD"){
       getFieldByName("My Example Field").setError("Incorrect prefix: " + prefix)
   }
   else if (!suffix.isInteger()){
       getFieldByName("My Example Field").setError("Incorrect suffix: " + suffix)
   }
   else {
       getFieldByName("My Example Field").clearError()
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the 3 problems raised

1. Add a validation checking the length of `field`. If it is less than 9 and you are expecting otherwise, throw an error.
2. Not sure about the syntax you used, if you are not particular with the case then `!"ABCD".equalsIgnoreCase(prefix)` might work, if you are then maybe `prefix != "ABCD"`
3. Depending on your "My Field" length requirement, when you substring `suffix`, do not hardcode 9 and use the field length instead. This should help validate if the characters after the 4th is integer from length 1 to x. I would add a check if the field length is 4, meaning there's no room for your numeric suffix.